# How to programmatically retrieve the configSource Location from config file

Tags: c#, web-config

Does anyone know how i can get the configSource value using standard API?

```
<appSettings configSource="AppSettings.config" />
```

Or do i need to parse the web.config in XML to get the value?

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the [AppSettingsSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection.aspx), then access its ElementInformation.Source property.

The link above contains information about how to access this section.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configSource"]
```

you need to add : `using System.Configuration;` namespace in your code

Answer (score 1):

Need to use the config manager as @competent_tech mentioned.

```
//open the config file..
Configuration config= ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
//read the ConfigSource
string configSourceFile = config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ConfigSource;
```

Comment: Yeah was onto that.  Seems like this code only works in EXE context.  Any ideas how to get it to work in ASP.NET context?

Comment: Sure...Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "web.config"));

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get the API to correctly load the AppSettings section correctly using the suggestions from @dbugger and @competent_tech.

> ```
> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.DefaultSection' to type
> ```
>
> 'System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection'.

Eventually went the XML route in just as many lines of code:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "web.config"));
var query = from e in xdoc.Descendants("appSettings")
            select e;

return query.First().Attribute("configSource").Value;
```

Thanks to all for the pointers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
<appSettings>
   <add  key="configSource" value="AppSettings.config"/>
   <add  key="anotherValueKey" value="anotherValue"/>
   <!-- You can put more ... -->
</appSettings>
```

And retrieve the value:

```
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configSource"];
string anotherValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["anotherValueKey"];
```

don't forget:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Comment: Then how do i access the keys in AppSettings.config?  Will ASP.NET  load the external config file?

Comment: I don't understand you. Do you want to load an AppSettings.config file? You can put some values or global parameters for your application in AppSettings section, then you retrieve that values. i edited my previous post.

Comment: Sorry i may not have been clear in my OP.  .NET configuration allows you to reference and store config data in external files.  All my appSettings keys are in external files.