# Get appSettings configSource from code

Tags: c#, .net, config, appsettings

Is there a way to retrieve configSource from code? I founded [How to programmatically retrieve the configSource Location from config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351377/how-to-programmatically-retrieve-the-configsource-location-from-config-file), but all answers are wrong.

I have following config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings configSource="appsettings.config"/>
</configuration>
```

When I tried to invoke following code:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var file = config.AppSettings.File;
```

`file` is always empty. Same is for `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configSource"]`. I think something changed in .NET 4, because answers are old ones.
I tried also `config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ConfigSource` but it is also empty.

I need this path to enable monitoring of `appSettings`. You could read more: [How to discover that appsettings changed in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211125/how-to-discover-that-appsettings-changed-in-c)

Comment: You can try using this and see if it returns the right configuration file back ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = configurationFilePath }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

Comment: The `ConfigSource` property didn't work? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx

Comment: @PeterRitchie I had to change something durring my tries. If you are interested how it works you could see my own answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some problems with this but I finally find an answer.

When config file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="appsettings.config"/>
</configuration>
```

The code above is working correctly:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var file = config.AppSettings.File;
```

But when config file is (it works same as above but syntax is different):

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings configSource="appsettings.config"/> <!-- configSource instead of file -->
</configuration>
```

I have to use following:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var file = config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ConfigSource;
```

So I have to check if `config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ConfigSource` and `config.AppSettings.File` is not an empty string and monitor correct one.